# How to detect first to finish request

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, concurrency, transactions, elixir

I have to post thousands of records to an endpoint that receives them and inserts them into a table. The back-end made in Elixir (with PostgreSQL) knows beforehand how many records will arrive in total. On the other hand the front-end sends the records simultaneously and in parts. For example, I have to send 100 records in chunks of 10. So 10 post requests are made to this endpoint. This works fine, but the problem is that when the last chunk is inserted I want to spawn a process that makes some calculations on the records, but I want this process to spawn only once. How can achieve this?

```
  def bulk_create(conn, %{"records" => records_params}) do
    with {rows_affected, nil} <- Api.create_records(records_params) do
      group = Api.get_group!(records_params |> first() |> Map.get("group_id"))
      total_records_saved = Api.count_records_by_group_id(group.id)
      finished = group.total_records == total_records_saved

      pid =
        if finished do
          {:ok, pid} =
            Processor.start_link(%{group_id: group.id, name: String.to_atom("PID.#{group.id}")})

          :erlang.pid_to_list(pid) |> List.delete_at(0) |> List.delete_at(-1) |> List.to_string()
        else
          nil
        end

      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> render("bulk_create.json",
        rows_affected: rows_affected,
        finished: finished,
        pid: pid
      )
    end
  end
```

This seems to work fine but if for any reason two requests insert at the same time they could obtain both true in this line

```
finished = group.total_records == total_records_saved
```

And both spawn the process.

Comment: You have to use locking to fix the race condition. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/avoid-race-condition-in-rails/ offers several options.

Comment: @btilly I'm not sure how to apply that with this case. I don't want to lock the inserts, I want the them to happen simultaneously.  I need that only one of the requests spawn the new process, not all of them. Maybe adding a new column to the group table and applying a lock there?

Comment: I would suggest at the beginning insert a record that this job has started, and at the end, before sending, update that record to the one launching  it. That puts a lock only on the attempt to launch the process.

Answer (score 1):

You need a state, and once you need a state in OTP, you are to launch a process.

It might be a simple [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html), or you might use built-in [`:counters`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/counters.html) or [`:persistent_term`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html).

The idea is you amend the value in the counter upon DB insert, which is an atomic operation, instead of relying on querying DB which is vulnerable to race conditions.

---

Another way around it would be to spawn a “throttler” which would queue DB requests, execute them, and ensure the calculation and cleanup starts before the `N+1`th record arrived.